# Scroll prevention sometimes working and sometimes not

Tags: reactjs

In my app, I use this code to prevent scrolling:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.onscroll = () => { window.scroll(0, 0); };
  },[]);
```

the code works for the most part, but sometimes when i reload the page it doesn't and I have 0 idea why, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

This is a longshot.

Its possible another library or your own code is overwriting `window.onscroll`. Thats one of the perils of those old window event hooks. Try registering a handler:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handler = window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        window.scroll(0, 0);
    })

    return () => window.removeEventListener(handler)
  },[]);
```